# In which all substituents does Inductive effect overpower Mesomeric effect?

Tags: organic-chemistry, resonance, electronegativity

In most substituents, the mesomeric effect is considered stronger and more dominating than the inductive effect.
A notable exception are the halogens.

The reason behind this has been well-explained [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/24572/13409).

I further had questions about the following:

- Since its about the EN, would all other electronegative elements with lone pair show this anomaly?
- Are there other substituents with this exceptional behavior?