# How do I decide the electromeric effect on pent-2-ene?

Tags: organic-chemistry

There are two possible case
**π electrons shifting to C2**
In this case, nucleophile attacks C3
It is stabilized by +I effect of two ethyl groups
**π electrons shifting to C3**
In this case, nucleophile attacks C2
It is stabilized by +I effect of a methyl group and a propyl group.

How do I decide which one is more stable, and ultimately, which one is favoured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here what you should consider first is **hyperconjugation**, rather than **inductive effect** (a [brief explanation by me](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/131101/odd-looking-carbocation-stability-order/131103#131103)).

You're right that $\ce{Nu-}$ will either attack on $\ce{C-3}$ or $\ce{C-2}$, and hence two carbocations would be formed. Now, we'll analyse the stability of these carbocations on the basis of hyperconjugation which is as follows,

- carbocation at $\ce{C-2}$ will have a total of 5 **HC** structures
- carbocation at $\ce{C-3}$ will have a total of 4 **HC** structures

Based on the above difference, it is easy to conclude that $\ce{Nu-}$ will attack on $\ce{C-2}$ carbon. Whereas based on inductive effect, those carbocations are nearly equally stable.

---

<sup>Note: HC is short for "hyperconjugative structures".</sup>

Comment: Oh thanks, but in my book it says that +I effect of c2h5>ch3 ,therefore electrons shifting to C2 is favoured more.any idea of what it's trying to say?

Comment: @DatBoi: your book had stated right order. It is bcoz of the fact that, ethyl group has two carbons, whereas methyl has only one. However, as you know that inductive effect isn't effective till next to neighbour C, hence the above diff. is near negligible. Also, in my [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/131101/odd-looking-carbocation-stability-order/131103#131103), I gave a brief explanation about the extent of stabilizing effect. So, any considerable diff. in hyperconjugation will overrule _small diff._ in inductive effect.

Comment: @YusufHasan: I think you've already noticed that I'd gave an explanation (short) on this in a previous answer. So, should I link that one in my post? it would be very effective, IMO.

Comment: Yusuf?! Who's that?

Comment: @DatBoi: [he is Yusuf Hasan](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/54655/yusuf-hasan). Actually, he added some suggestion just after your comment, and then deleted it ahead of my comment.